# Ampscript for Uppercase hyphenated values

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-template, lookup, regular-expressions

I've been trying to solve an Ampscript code, but keep getting the same results. What am I doing wrong?

For /* Case 1: Uppercase hyphenated */
a) the original value looks like this A-BCDE
b) the required output should be A-Bcde,
c) but current result with this Ampscript is A-bcde

```ampscript
%%[
/* Retrieves the ProductNameText for the given ProductID */
var @ProductID, @lookupResult2, @ProductNameText, @finalText
set @ProductID = AttributeValue("ProductID")
set @lookupResult2 = LookupRows("DATA EXTENSION", "ProductID", @ProductID)
    
if RowCount(@lookupResult2) > 0 then
   set @ProductNameText = Field(Row(@lookupResult2, 1), "ProductNameText")
    
    /* Case 1: Uppercase hyphenated */
    if RegExMatch(@CRMModelGroupText1, "^[A-Z]+-[A-Z]+$", 0) == 1 then
        set @firstPart = ProperCase(SubString(@ProductNameText, 1, Subtract(IndexOf(@ProductNameText, "-"), 1)))
         set @secondPart = ProperCase(SubString(@ProductNameText, Add(IndexOf(@ProductNameText, "-"), 1), 1))
         set @thirdPart = SubString(@ProductNameText, Add(IndexOf(@ProductNameText, "-"), 2), Length(@ProductNameText))
         set @finalText = Concat(@firstPart, "-", @secondPart, @thirdPart)
    
     /* Other Cases */
     else
         /* Case 2: Uppercase compound name */
         if RegExMatch(@ProductNameText, "^[A-Z\s]+$", 0) == 1 then
             set @finalText = ProperCase(@ProductNameText)
    
         /* Case 3: Uppercase single word */
         elseif RegExMatch(@ProductNameText, "^[A-Z]+$", 0) == 1 then
             set @finalText = ProperCase(@ProductNameText)
  
         /* Case 4: Uppercase multiple words */
         else
             set @parts = BuildRowSetFromString(@ProductNameText, " ")
             set @finalText = ProperCase(Field(Row(@parts, 1), 1))
         endif
     endif
    
     set @@ProductNameText = @finalText
 else
     set @ProductNameText = ""
 endif
]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "Case 1" block appears to disassemble then reassemble the word correctly, but it'll still run into the issue with `ProperCase` treating that as a single word and capitalizing the first letter only.

As an alternative, you can try processing each word individually first:

```ampscript
%%[

set @value = "A-BCDE"
set @delim = "-"

/* hyphen gets consumed, so restore later */
set @parts = BuildRowsetFromString(@value, @delim)

/* init */
set @finalValue = ""

for @i = 1 to RowCount(@parts) do
  set @row = Row(@parts, @i)

  /* process each part individually */
  set @part = ProperCase(Field(@row, 1))

  /* restore hyphen (we're prepending, so skip first iteration) */
  if @i > 1 then
    set @part = Concat(@delim, @part)
  endif

  /* combine parts */
  set @finalValue = Concat(@finalValue, @part)
next @i

output(v(@finalValue)) /* A-Bcde */

]%%
```

This should work with zero or more hyphens regardless of position.

Also, not sure if this was a copy-paste error, but the `set @@ProductNameText = @finalText` has an extra `@` (not sure if that's contributing to any undefined behavior).